What exactly does the <name> parameter of \pdfbookmark in hyperref do?
The official hyperref documentation (section 6.1.1) states that in
\pdfbookmark[<level>]{<text>}{<name>}

the parameter
<name> provides the internal anchor name and consequently should be unique. I suppose, although I am not sure, that the internal anchor name is basically what is set with \label{}, but in the present case I don't see why it should be set, and in fact playing around I've seen it cannot even be referred to through \ref{<name>}. Moreover, no strange behaviour seems to occur if I choose to leave <name> empty every time, and the document outline comes out as expected.
Consequently, the question: what exactly is the role of the parameter <name> and why should it be unique?

I should clarify that, after following the chosen answer, I realize that setting the same <name> for more than one entry does lead to undesired behaviour, namely jumping to the position of to the first bookmark named with <name> , whenever one clicks on a bookmark with that same name.

Bookmarks typically jump to some place in the document, a destination which has a name.
Hyperref creates this destination from this argument and in the PDF you then find GoTo objects:
<< /S /GoTo /D (a.0) >>

If the name is not unique, hyperref will complain destination with the same identifier (name{a.0}) and the link will be wrong: Click on Text A and Text B in the bookmarks and compare it with Text C.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\pdfbookmark{Text A}{a}Text A

\newpage
\pdfbookmark{Text B}{a}Text B

\newpage 
\pdfbookmark{Text C}{c}Text C
\end{document}

The name is created from the argument together with the optional argument (the level) which is by default 0, that's why you see a.0 in the message above. So the claim that the name must be unique is not fully correct, but imho good enough for most uses ...
